# What is an EEEEE Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an ***EEEEE Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| EEEEE Words™ | Not EEEEE Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ADEXE | NAU |
| ATWIST | ATWIRL |
| BISTRO | CAFE |
| CHAI | LATTE |
| CODEX | MANUSCRIPT |
| CON | PRO |
| ESTRUS | HEAT |
| FEINTS | STABS |
| GOTCHA | SNAFU |
| INDEX | UNINDEXED |
| JEWISH | GENTILE |
| MOCHA | FRAPPE |
| NINTH | SIXTH |
| PASTRY | COOKIE |
| QUAINT | CHARMING |
| RECONS | SORTIES |
| SCONES | TARTS |
| SWISH | TWIRL |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
EEEEE Words™,Not EEEEE Words™
ADEXE,NAU
ATWIST,ATWIRL
BISTRO,CAFE
CHAI,LATTE
CODEX,MANUSCRIPT
CON,PRO
ESTRUS,HEAT
FEINTS,STABS
GOTCHA,SNAFU
INDEX,UNINDEXED
JEWISH,GENTILE
MOCHA,FRAPPE
NINTH,SIXTH
PASTRY,COOKIE
QUAINT,CHARMING
RECONS,SORTIES
SCONES,TARTS
SWISH,TWIRL
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is an EEEEE Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of EEEEE Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An EEEEE word is one that

> contains one of STR, CON DEX, INT, WIS, CHA as a substring, and is at most 6 letters long.

This is of course

> a reference to Dungeons and Dragons, whose players have attributes with those (abbreviated) names. The latest version of that game is the Fifth Edition, which I think is often written as "5E"; hence EEEEE in the title.

So, why

> the artificial-looking restriction to length <= 6? It turns out after some discussion with Rubio in TSL that the conceit is that each word corresponds to one of the three 6-sided dice rolled to generate a player character's attributes. In the given list there are three words for each attribute, so this player's character has STR of 6+6+6=18 (three 6-letter words), INT of 6+5+6=17, and so on. Obviously, none of this is part of the actual rule; it merely explains why the rule is what it is.

The simpler version of the rule

> without that restriction, of course, is refuted by the examples of UNINDEXED and CHARMING.

Thanks to John Clifford for pointing out in comments

> that all the EEEEE words are rather short

and to Rubio for some clarification in TSL.

Comment: You've definitely identified the source of the puzzle name and the basic idea of the rule, but those two misclassified ones have got me stuck too.

Comment: I just confirmed against the other editions and the stats are the same across the editions.

Comment: I don't know if it helps at all but the two we're trying to figure out are also the longest strings in the list with the exception of manuscript; none of the EEEEE words are longer than 6 characters.

Comment: True. (Which does provide an explanation that fits everything, though I don't like it.)

Comment: Come to think of it, if you look at how many 6-character EEEEE words there are, it doesn't seem like a ludicrous idea to suggest that the presence of charming and unindexed are there precisely to point out that character count can prevent a word from meeting the requirement.

Comment: If the rule limits it to exactly one of the attribute abbreviations, that would fit your amended answer and explain why you can't have an EEEEE word longer than 6 characters.

Comment: CONSTRAINT is NOT an EEEEE word

Comment: well, if not CONSTRAINT then let's fall back to the slightly more inelegant "length <= 6". I think we're still owed some more examples :-).

Comment: If your longer explanation is the one Rubio intended, I feel that this skirts going against "The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is an EEEEE Word™ without relying on the other words." But yeah, now that it's laid out like that the D6 connection makes sense.

Comment: It no more than skirts it. The actual condition is simply content + length; the other stuff is motivation for that condition, not the condition itself. It makes me a bit uncomfortable too, though. In any case, Rubio has explicitly confirmed this in TSL chat.

Comment: Well then allow me to congratulate you on a well-deserved tick. :)